# Sharing my 240V 30amp between two dryers

Tags: wiring, transfer-switch

We are running a clothes dryer in the lower level of our home. We are installing a washer and dryer on our main level.
Can I split the power feed between both dryers and what can I use and where can it be bought.
We only want to run one dryer at a time when needed.

Comment: Is the panel not accessible for installation of additional circuits? What's your motivation here?

Comment: Do you have a clothes washer down there as well?

Comment: panel not accusable. I would like to use a manual switch I possiable.

Comment: The question you posed has been answered. If you have a followup, please start a new question after resolving this one.

Answer (score 2):

No. The wiring and the breaker are sized for the needs of a single dryer. To connect several would create a situation where overload is likely, or at least a possibility.

A possible workaround, with questions of legality outstanding, would be to install a lockout mechanism or switch that would prevent simultaneous use of both dryers.

Comment: Yes, we only want to use a single dryer at a time not simultaneously.

Comment: The question on the floor is "how do you enforce that mechanically".  Better if it's a method that doesn't abruptly shut off a dryer that's underway.

Answer (score 1):

As isherwood says, "No".  On a circuit that traditionally drives one single appliance, it violates Code to rely on citizens to use a procedure to avoid overloading it.** Overload protection is by no means perfect, and you can't rely on the 30A circuit breaker to enforce "don't use simultaneously".

You could do it with a latching relay.  I would wire the relay controls in 24VAC.  Each dryer gets a "gimme" pushbutton, when pressed, throws over the relay to supply that dryer, and it stays there indefinitely.  Add a 240V green indicator light to show "you got power, stop pushing the button".

Interrupting a dry underway is a problem. It's hard on the contacts and will cause great inconvenience (I would get back to my dryer 24 hours later and find wet moldy clothes).  So you might add a circuit to disallow changeover if a machine is underway, by disconnecting the 24V system.  One way might be to "sense" current with a NC type reed switch; loop each hot a few times around the switch (opposing directions so the magnetic fields stack instead of cancel).  You could add a 24V amber lamp across the button showing "switchable".

The 24V parts need to be in different boxes/compartments than the 240V parts.

Other arrangements could be possible; you could use a plain relay and a "run down" timer to let A have the dryer for up to 1 hour, then it autothrows back to B.

** There's some blah-blah in the Code that confuses me as to whether a 30A circuit is allowed to have multiple receptacles; a guy with a welder once challenged me and said "Why not?" and I couldn't find a code section to refute it.  However, I'm fairly sure your local inspector won't allow it, and if you press the point, he'll just ask the town council to prohibit it.

Comment: If I may ask, what part of the Code are you looking at and getting confused by re: multiple receptacles on a 30A circuit? (Although even I'd think that multiple receptacles on a 30A circuit in a dwelling unit would at least raise inspector eyebrows...)

Comment: I was looking around 210.23(B) but I may be barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't seem to say explicitly in Code that you can't have multiple receptacles on a 30, 40, or 50A branch circuit...

Comment: I have installed quite a few systems with multiple receptacles all 30 & 50 don't remember any 40's usually in garages / workshops never had a inspector challenge them. In my own shop each bay had 1 240 circuit with a receptacle at each end.